# Unit test AJAX with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing

Can anyone provide me a simple example how to test AJAX in WordPress?
Especially if your AJAX is located in `functions.php` which is a procedural code.

Comment: Your AJAX would not be located in a PHP file.

Comment: Google revealed this https://deliciousbrains.com/unit-testing-ajax-api-requests-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: The article Jay Blanchard just posted is what I followed, and continue to reference, when writing my own unit tests. That's your answer right there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this what you’re asking, but Devin Price at wptheming.com gives the best example I have read of how AJAX works with WordPress. It really made things click for me when I was learning how to use AJAX in the WordPress environment.

Below is a link to the article:
http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

I also did my own post on How to Make a Wordpress AJAX Call, so if you are interested in that you can check it out here:
http://sharewebdesign.com/blog/wordpress-ajax-call/

I hope this helps.